# Require JavaScript to reevaluate IF criteria on each page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a script to inject some HTML element into a page using JavaScript based on criteria in the URL. It works as expected, but when I click on a new tab/page that no longer meets the criteria, that HTML element still shows up. Is there a way reevaluate on each refresh of the page?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
   if (/frequently-asked-questions/i.test(self.location.href)) {
        $('.myTitle').before('<p>Additional Text on FAQ</p>');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Not enough info, if you're reloading the page, it would re-evaluate. You need to explain a lot more about the environment and the surrounding HTML

Comment: I was worried that might be the case.., so it sounds like the code itself is perfectly fine, but the environment itself might be a little tricky to figure out. I'll see what else I can find. Thanks.